# How to allow image to alight outside of the parent content

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time with css. I have a content that content class a image and a text. I would like to align the text to the right side of the screen but I do not want to limit the image to the width of the content. I would like to allow the image go outside.

I tried to play with positions and "fixed" allow me to move the image outside of the content by the content height changes de-coupling  the image.

```
<div class="content2">
  <img id="cloudimg" src=".\Cloud.jpg">
  <p>Cloud Computing</p>

</div>
```

and in my css

```
.parallax-wrapper-cloud {
  width: 460px;
  height:180vh;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  padding-top:20vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parallax-wrapper-cloud::before {

  content:"";
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color: #ffddfbff;
  !background-image: url("./bkg4.jpg");
  !background-repeat: no-repeat;
  !background-position: left;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  transform:translateZ(-1px) scale(2);

}


.content2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #black;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 100;
    background: #ee0d0d;

}
```

this is what I see (right side the image is truncated):

```
----------------------
|                    |
|  ---------------   |
|  |    half      |  |
|  |    image     |  |
|  |              |  |
|  ---------------   |
|   Cloud Computing  |
|                    |
----------------------
```

this is what I would like to see (image full displayed and partially outside):

```
  ----------------------
  |                    |
---------------        |
|    full      |       |
|    image     |       |
|              |       |
---------------        |
  |   Cloud Computing  |
  |                    |
  ----------------------
```

as described above

Answer (score 3):

```css
.content2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #black;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #ee0d0d;
    text-align: center;
}

#cloudimg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-40%);
}
```

```html
<div class="content2">
  <img id="cloudimg" src="https://i1.wp.com/amergin.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/image-placeholder.jpg?ssl=1">
  <p>Cloud Computing</p>

</div>
```

Comment: this transform: translate(-40%); worked like a charm... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to move the image a bit to the left without messing up the general flow of your site, you might want to use `transform: translateX(-100px);`. The `-100px` should be replaced by the amount of pixels (or cm/in/pt/pc/em/...) you want the image to be moved.
What this does is that it takes the object and just moves it, **without** affecting the document flow. That means that the other object will position themselfs as if the object wasn't moved at all, because this transformation happens after everything is positioned.
If you want to read more, I recommend reading [this article on w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) or to look at the `translate` specification [here on the MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate).

Note that you can also use a percentage like `transform: translateX(-50%);`, but the percentage is relative to the object itself, so `-50%` will move an 1000px wide object 500px to the left.

In your case, I would recommend something like

```
#cloudimg {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}
```